# Append text inside NSTextField

Tags: macos, cocoa, nstextfield, ibaction

I have a button that when pressed sends a text string to an `NSTextField`. 
I want to be able to send more strings to this field when a button is pressed. However, when another button is pressed it deletes the contents inside the field and replaces it.

```
@IBAction func t1(_ sender: Any) {
    solution.stringValue = "- Test"
}

@IBAction func t2(_ sender: Any) {
    solution.stringValue = "- Test2"
}
```

Above is two separate buttons. 
If **t1** button is pressed it sends **"Test"** to `solution.stringValue`.

If I click the second button **t2**, I want it to also populate `solution.stringValue` without deleting what is already in the `NSTextField`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@IBAction func t2(_ sender: Any) {
    solution.stringValue += "- Test2"
}
```